# Can I load cucumber feature files from gitlab into JIRA?

Tags: cucumber, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-plugin

Let's say that 
- I have a project on gitlab which has cucumber feature files.
- I have a JIRA board with JIRA stories.
- I am required to write tests for most of these stories **and make them available in JIRA.**

Now, the main advantage of having these feature files is that we don't have to write separate manual tests for this.

For now, I have to copy the feature files that I wrote in my project and paste them to JIRA 
AND
 do it every time I make any changes to the feature files.

Is there any way (A plugin in JIRA/jenkins), I could have JIRA load the cucumber files from my gitlab project or Jenkins server?

Comment: Can you add a link to the file from Jira and have people follow the link to the version controlled file?

Comment: Not always. If the script reviewers are not from my firm but from a client firm, we give them access to JIRA but not our gitlab content.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [AssertThat BDD & Test Management in Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219033/assertthat-bdd-test-management-in-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

Provides end-to-end integration - from features creation to manual and automated tests execution and reporting. Out of the box integration with test automation frameworks through plugins.

Intead of synchronising feature files every time you edit them in gitlab, just store and manage them directly in Jira and download before the test run using plugin for your chosen framework (currently supports Maven, Gradle and Rake integration as well as command line tool which is framework/language agnostic.)

More info and usage examples on website https://www.assertthat.com/